# Table with lots of text columns. Should I use nvarchar or text?

Tags: sql-server

I have table with 210 text columns.

The columns contain a kind of comments and are not always filled.

What is a better solution: NVARCHAR(2000) or TEXT?

If I choose NVARCHAR and I wanted (in the future) to increase the number of characters to NVARCHAR(8000), is this affects the physical size of a row?

Comment: Text data type will be Deprecated,
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms143729.aspx
why not varchar type

Comment: As @NeerajPrasadSharma mentioned text, ntext and image will be deprecated. Use `nvarchar(MAX)` instead.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Text types are deprecated:

> ntext , text, and image data types will be removed in a future version of Microsoft SQL Server. Avoid using these data types in new development work, and plan to modify applications that currently use them. Use nvarchar(max), varchar(max), and varbinary(max) instead.

see MSDN: [ntext, text, and image](https://msdn.microsoft.com/fr-fr/library/ms187993%28v=SQL.120%29.aspx)

Therefore you should use varchar(x) or nvarchar(x) if you need unicode.
You must choose a size big enough for what you want to store or use varchar(max). 
Besides, each column does not need to be set with a similar size.

The physical size of variable length type is based on what you store in it. If you later decide to change the size from 100 to 1000, a 50 characters long string will still occupy the same number of byte. However, a 200 characters string will only fit in a (n)varchar(1000) or at least varchar(200).

If you have a lot of null value, you should consider using the SPARSE option.
This MSDN link gives more details and data on potential gain on SPARSE columns. You can expect a 40% in a varchar column containing 60% null values.
[Use Sparse Columns](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc280604.aspx)

Answer (score 2):

Let's start with the fact that `text`, `ntext` and `image` are all deprecated.
[According to MSDN:](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187993.aspx)

> ntext, text, and image data types will be removed in a future version of Microsoft SQL Server. Avoid using these data types in new development work, and plan to modify applications that currently use them. Use nvarchar(max), varchar(max), and varbinary(max) instead.

Now let's deal with the fact that since 2005 version, you can specify `max` as the length of columns, effectively eliminating the need for
`text`, `ntext` and `image` - the replacements are
`varchar(max)`, `nvarchar(max)` and `varbinary(max)` respectively.

As for storage size:
for [`varchar`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms176089.aspx) and [`varbinary`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188362.aspx), The storage size is the actual length of the data entered + 2 bytes.

for [`nvarchar`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186939.aspx), > The storage size, in bytes, is two times the actual length of data entered + 2 bytes.

All this information is available in the MSDN pages I've linked to.

Answer (score 1):

Don't use `TEXT`, it's deprecated!

Use `NVARCHAR`, if you expect international data (special characters) and if the size of your db is not important.

Using `VARCHAR` or `NVARCHAR` stores a reference to the actual string within your row. No problem to define `VARCHAR(MAX)` or `NVARCHAR(MAX)` right from the beginning. It will not take more place than starting with a smaller amount.

How many rows will there be? What is the expected percentage of your columns to be filled? Will the structure change in future? How are these values used? Will you filter them? Search them? Search for text parts?

You see, the answer is not that easy :-)

You should read about SPARSE columns (very good, if you have a high "not filled" rate) or even an XML column